# Foundationpress npm install deprecated error

Tags: node.js, npm, zurb-foundation, lodash, deprecated

I seem to get npm install errors on both JointsWP and Foundationpress.

running npm install in foundationpress from the command line results in this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-minify-css@1.2.4: Please use gulp-clean-css
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node release >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in tree.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continueing fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running command line in Administrator mode? When I moved from Foundationpress 5 to 6 I had to start running my command line as an administrator or I got a whole bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, these are not *errors*, they are *warnings* and can be ignored. Don't just trust me, the creator of FoundationPress [says so](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/issues/827#issuecomment-225002931):

> These are warnings, not errors. No need to worry as long as FoundationPress is working and you're able to run the `npm run build` and `npm run watch` commands.

*Edit: Oh, I just realized you where the one being answered in that issue. So you probably already know this by now :)*

Second, when it comes to graceful-fs:

You can check which package is using the deprecated version of graceful-fs with `npm ls graceful-fs`, if you do that you'll see that it is (probably) gulp using the deprecated version. The gulp team is [aware of the issue](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1571):

> We are aware of the graceful-fs deprecation warning upon install of
>   gulp 3.x.
>
> This is due to:
>
> 1. our graceful-fs devDependency
> 2. the vinyl-fs dependency
>
> Both of which we are unable to upgrade due to API breaking changes.
>
> There is nothing wrong with the dependency, especially since it is
>   only used in development. We will be updating or removing it in gulp 4
>   and the message will go away.

So, don't worry about it!

(Also, if you use `npm install --no-optional` instead of `npm install` you will see less warnings.)